# The different results of the definite integral by two methods

Tags: definite-integrals

\begin{array}{l}
Find\ the\ value\ of\int _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{3\pi }{2}}\sqrt{( 1+sin\theta )^{2} +cos( \theta )^{2}} d\theta \\
\\
Method\ 1\ :\ Substitution\\
\int \sqrt{( 1+sin\theta )^{2} +cos( \theta )^{2}} d\theta \\
=\int \sqrt{1+2sin\theta +sin^{2} \theta +cos^{2} \theta } d\theta \\
=\int \sqrt{2+2sin\theta } d\theta \\
=\sqrt{2}\int ( 1+sin\theta )^{\frac{1}{2}} d\theta \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Let\ t=1+sin\theta ,\ dt=cos\theta d\theta \\
=\sqrt{2}\int t^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \frac{dt}{cos\theta } \ \ \ cos\theta =\sqrt{1-( t-1)^{2}}\\
=\sqrt{2}\int t^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \left( 1-( t-1)^{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dt\\
\\
=\sqrt{2}\int \left(\frac{1}{2-t}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} dt\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Let\ v=2-t,\ dv=-dt\\
=-\sqrt{2}\int v^{-\frac{1}{2}} dv\\
=-2\sqrt{2}( 1-sin\theta )^{\frac{1}{2}} +C\\
\\
\int _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{3\pi }{2}}\sqrt{( 1+sin\theta )^{2} +cos( \theta )^{2}} d\theta =-2\sqrt{2}( 1-sin\theta )^{\frac{1}{2}} \mid _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{3\pi }{2}} =-4\\
\\
Method\ 2:\ \\
\\
\int \sqrt{( 1+sin\theta )^{2} +cos( \theta )^{2}} d\theta \\
=\sqrt{2}\int \sqrt{( 1+sin\theta )} d\theta \ \ \\
=\sqrt{2}\int \sqrt{\left( sin\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) +cos\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)\right)^{2}} d\theta \ \\
=\sqrt{2}\left(\int sin\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) d\theta +\int cos\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) d\theta \right)\\
=2\sqrt{2}\left( sin\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) -cos\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)\right) +C\\
\\
\int _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{3\pi }{2}}\sqrt{( 1+sin\theta )^{2} +cos( \theta )^{2}} d\theta =2\sqrt{2}\left( sin\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) -cos\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)\right) \mid _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{3\pi }{2}} =4
\end{array}
I want to know what is wrong with Method 1. 
I've spent a lot of time checking the steps. Please help!

Comment: You forgot the second value..

Comment: Same thing in the method 2, when taking $\sqrt{\left(\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^2} = \left|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right|$, you have to show somehow that $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\ge 0$ for $\frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le\frac{3\pi}{2}$, before changing to $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: @Gonçalo Thank you very much!!!!!!!

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin　Thanks for your reminder.